# jquery элемент вызвавший функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет есть код.

```
<input id="sort" oninput="update(this.value)" type="text" value="">
```

я хочу в функции обратится к элементу который вызвал функцию.
Пишу но не чего не выходит

```
function update(value)
{
   $(this).css(//код);
}
```

Хотел избавится от `oninput="update(this.value)"`
сделав

```
function update() 
{
   $(this).css({ "fontSize": "40" })
}
$(document).ready($("#sort").update());
```

Но тоже не вышло(
Так как обратится в функции  к элементу  который вызвал функцию.
И если можете напишите как сделать второй варинат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вам надо, собственно, и передавать в функцию сам элемент (this), а не его значение (this.value). А в функции им манипулировать

```js
function update(el) {
    var myEl = $(el);
  
    console.log(myEl.val());
    myEl.css({'width': (myEl.width() + 10) + 'px', 'height': (myEl.height() + 10) + 'px'}); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sort" oninput="update(this)" type="text" value="">
```

---

jquery - `oninput="update(this)"` уже не требуется

```js
$("#sort").on('keyup', function() {
  update(this);
});

function update(el) {    
  var myEl = $(el);
  
  console.log(myEl.val());    
  myEl.css({'width': (myEl.width() + 10) + 'px', 'height': (myEl.height() + 10) + 'px'}); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sort" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Спасибо  за овтет